# Is there a way to set AVSpeechBoundary to a certain value or after the sentence is completed?

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I want to pause speech utterance and it has to complete the current sentence it is speaking out then it has to pause but the API provides only two pause types immediate and word not current sentence. I tried this,

```
 myutterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string:readTextView.text)

 synth .speak(myutterance)

 synth .pauseSpeaking(at: AVSpeechBoundary.immediate)
```

But it pauses immediately after text is completed.

Comment: Did you try postUtteranceDelay?

Comment: No i want to pauseSpeaking after a sentence.i am just getting boundary immediate and word

Comment: Is their any way to do that @satheeshwaran.Any help would be appreciated.Thankyou

Comment: I am working on this, interesting issue here. Give me some time, I am making a sample for you.

Comment: Just to confirm you want some time between each of your sentences right? Like a pause before beginning the next?

Comment: No sir,i am doing a text to speech project.If i am pausing the audio the audio should only paused after completing the sentence.Not immediatly.Thanks for the help.can u please find an answer?

Comment: try my answer I am able to pause one second after every sentence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just tried whatever you did and it read the whole sentence without giving enough pause,

```
let someText = "Some Sample text. That will read and pause after every sentence"

let speechSynthesizer = AVSpeechSynthesizer()

let myutterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string:someText)

speechSynthesizer .speak(myutterance)

//Normal reading without pause
speechSynthesizer .pauseSpeaking(at: AVSpeechBoundary.immediate)
```

To pause after every sentence you can break the whole text to simple components and read them individually in a loop like below by using the postUtteranceDelay property.

```
//To pause after every sentence
let components = someText.components(separatedBy: ".")

for str in components{

    let myutterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string:str)

    speechSynthesizer .speak(myutterance)

    myutterance.postUtteranceDelay = 1 //Set it to whatever value you would want.
}
```

To pause after completing the currently speaking sentence we need to do a tiny hack,

```
var isPaused:Bool = false
let someText = "Some Sample text. That will read and pause after every sentence. The next sentence should'nt be heard if you had pressed the pause button. Let us try this."
let speechSynthesizer = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
var currentUtterance:AVSpeechUtterance?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    speechSynthesizer.delegate = self
}

@IBAction func startSpeaking(_ sender: Any) {

    //Pause after every sentence
    let components = someText.components(separatedBy: ".")

    for str in components{

        let myutterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string:str)

        speechSynthesizer .speak(myutterance)

        myutterance.postUtteranceDelay = 1
    }
}

@IBAction func pauseSpeaking(_ sender: Any) {
    isPaused = !isPaused
}

func speechSynthesizer(_ synthesizer: AVSpeechSynthesizer, willSpeakRangeOfSpeechString characterRange: NSRange, utterance: AVSpeechUtterance){
    print("location\(characterRange.location)")
    print("Range + Length\(characterRange.location + characterRange.length)")
    print("currentUtterance!.speechString\(currentUtterance!.speechString)")
    print("currentUtterance!.count\(currentUtterance!.speechString.characters.count)")

    if isPaused && (characterRange.location + characterRange.length) == currentUtterance!.speechString.characters.count{
        speechSynthesizer.stopSpeaking(at:.word)
    }

}

func speechSynthesizer(_ synthesizer: AVSpeechSynthesizer, didStart utterance: AVSpeechUtterance){
    currentUtterance = utterance
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir.But my problem is that i am using one pause button.If i clicked on that button while playing it should pause only after that sentence is completed.

Comment: Okay you could have been clear. So you want to pause after completing the current sentence right?

Comment: yes Sir.thats what i want..thank you for your valuable time

Comment: We should use this delegate method func speechSynthesizer(_ synthesizer: AVSpeechSynthesizer, willSpeakRangeOfSpeechString characterRange: NSRange, utterance: AVSpeechUtterance)

Comment: @farzeen You are welcome, Accept & Upvote the answer then!

Comment: Sure sir @satheeshwaran

Comment: Sir,But i cant resume the audio while here you are using stopSpeaking.The audio is starting from begining

Comment: Sir i checked with that one but it is not working currectly

Comment: @farzeen Dude you gotta implemet that in pause method. resume speaking there.

Comment: @satheeshwaran.thats the problem.Is their any other way to do that

Comment: @satheeshwaran.Sir Thanks for the help

Comment: @satheeshwaran.No sir i am trying but it is not working.While giving stopSpeaking i cant resume the audio

Comment: @farzeen Stop calling me Sir, I too tried but no luck. pauseSpeaking never stops the speech something weird is happening here. Did you check on an actual device?

Comment: @satheeshwaran.I am trying in iphone 6